# Ajax success case not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have this function (part of the whole code):

```html
function helloDear_javascript() { ?>
 <script type="text/javascript" >
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#id").click(function(){
   $('.input_triplify').each(function(k,v){
    var mk  = $(this).attr('mk');
    var v = $(this).val();
    if(v != 'correspondencia' &&  $.trim(v) != ''){

     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: {action: 'triplify', meta: mk, value: v },//, valores_coluna_posts:
      dataType: 'json',
      success:
       function(data){
        console.log(data);
       },
      error:
       function(data){
        alert('ocorreu um erro ao acessar o banco, favor pesquisar novamente.');
       }
     });
    }
   });
      $("#corpo").hide(1000);
   $("#corpo2").show(1000);
   
    });
 });
 </script> <?php
}
```

The problem is: my friend is running it in xampp, windows 8.1 and wordpress 4. It is OK, returning the console.log(data). With the same code, I am running it in apache, xubuntu updated and wordpress 4. It is not OK, always goes to the error case. I can't find why this is happening because is the same whole code, DB, web browser, etc. If I make a change, placing console.log(data) in error case, it returns (viewing from console menu of the web browser):

```
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(),
```

It never goes to the success case, no matter what I do!

Thanks!

Comment: Check the network panel in the browser console. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network

Comment: Check once is `ajaxurl` going to correct path or not.

Comment: What is the `ajaxurl`? please post.

Comment: Thanks but the path seems to be ok

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your `ajaxurl` contains some cross domain request value (or at least this is what the browser thinks - if you use your `LAN IP address /192.168.1.10/` instead `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` for access it).

As you know, JavaScript Ajax cross domain requests are denied from execution (although this restriction can be bypassed). The point for this restriction is to **prevent your site from reading data from a remote site**, not to prevent it sending data.

For example, you can't make my browser go to my bank and fetch my account details so you can send them to your web server.

The [same origin policy](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) wouldn't prevent you submitting a request that money be transfered to your server, but that is why sites have to implement defenses against [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Try testing the code by adding `crossDomain: true,` in your AJAX request after `type: "POST"`.

**EDIT:**

Some explanation about jQuery `error` state: 
This is a [function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to be called **if the request fails** (that means your browser under Linux cannot send proper `XMLHttpRequest`).

The function receives three arguments: The `jqXHR` (in jQuery 1.4.x, `XMLHttpRequest`) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides `null`) are `timeout`, `error`, `abort`, and `parsererror`. When an HTTP error occurs, `errorThrown` receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as `Not Found` or `Internal Server Error.` As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn.

Note: This handler is not called **for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests**, that means that if your script goes to the `error` condition, it is not cross-domain request issue, it is browser problem.

Comment: i use localhost for access it